„Anlässlich" vs „Aufgrund"?
Bei so einem Satz

Die Demonstration, anlässlich derer wir einen Umweg machen mussten,
dauert eine Weile noch.

könnte man auch „aufgrund" benutzen?

Die Demonstration, aufgrund derer wir einen Umweg machen mussten,
dauert eine Weile noch.

Wenn nicht, warum nicht?  Was ist der Unterschied im Allgemeinem zwischen „anlässlich" und „aufgrund"?

Hier passt für mich nur "aufgrund".

Der Unterschied zwischen anlässlich und aufgrund ist grundsätzlich der zwischen Grund und Anlass. Ein Grund drückt klare Kausalität aus: Wegen der Demonstration musstet ihr einen Umweg nehmen, gäbe es sie nicht, hättet ihr keinen Umweg genommen.
Menschen haben aber einen freien Willen, und ist gibt Ereignisse, die der Grund der Handlung sind, die dich aber nicht wirklich dazu zwingen etwas zu tun. Das ist ein Anlass. Beispiele erklären das besser:

Anlässlich des 225. Geburtstages wurden im Januar 2022 eine Sonderbriefmarke und eine 20-Euro-Silbermünze herausgegeben.

Hieran sieht man auch die klare Assoziation von Anlass mit Jubiläen und Feiern. Das muss nicht so sein:

Vielleicht ist die Aktion feindlich, aber ist sie der Anlass für einen Krieg?

von wiktionary. Rein von der Bedeutung ist Vorwand ähnlich, dieses Wort delegitimiert allerdings die Handlung.
In deinem Satz

Die Demonstration, anlässlich derer wir einen Umweg machen mussten, dauert eine Weile noch.

ist es daher seltsam, anlässlich mit müssen zu verwenden. aufgrund ist da die bessere Wahl. Die Positionierung von noch ist etwas unnatürlich, ich würde

Die Demonstration, aufgrund derer wir einen Umweg machen mussten, dauert noch eine Weile.

sagen.
en
The difference between anlässlich and aufgrund boils down to the difference between Grund and Anlass. Grund is just "reason", the event that causes another event. There was a demonstration, so you had to take a detour. The causality is clear. Without the demonstration, you would not have taken a detour, with the demonstration, you had to.
While some events might be the reason someone does something, it does not force them to do so. That's an Anlass. But examples explain this better.

Anlässlich des 225. Geburtstages wurden im Januar 2022 eine Sonderbriefmarke und eine 20-Euro-Silbermünze herausgegeben.
On the occasion of the 225th birthday, ...

While a birthday is certainly a reason, no one is obliged to do anything for a birthday, but they use it as occasion. If you look through the examples at DWDS, you'll see that it is often connected to celebrations, but

Vielleicht ist die Aktion feindlich, aber ist sie der Anlass für einen Krieg? 
Perhaps the action is hostile, but is it the occasion for war?

from wiktionary shows that is not always the case. A similar word is Vorwand (pretext) which however delegitimates the reason unlike Anlass.
In your sentence

Die Demonstration, anlässlich derer wir einen Umweg machen mussten, dauert eine Weile noch.

it therefore strange to use anlässlich together with müssen and using aufgrund would be the better choice. The placement of noch is a bit unnatural, so I would use

Die Demonstration, aufgrund derer wir einen Umweg machen mussten, dauert noch eine Weile.


Deutsche Frage, englische Antwort?

@Olafant Ups, ich übersetze mal...
